# . How to create a CubeScene in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a CubeScene outside of my actual Scene. So I can use the CubeScene as a "room", where my object is located in.

I have found some code snippets, but they are not working for me. It should create a Cuberoom, with 6 sides, if I understand the functionality of this code snippet right. I attached to all 6 sides the texture *blau.png*, which is blue. So I should be able to see a blue room, where my object is located in. But what I get is simply no Cuberoom. Just the object.

(and of course I render the scene, camera and sceneCube, cameraCube in the render function)

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
camera.position.set( 8000, 0, cameraOffset ); 

cameraCube = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 20000 );
cameraCube.position.set( 80, 0, cameraOffset );  

sceneCube = new THREE.Scene();
sceneCube.add(cameraCube);

//---------------------

var r = "././images/";
    var urls = [
        r + "blau.png", r + "blau.png",
        r + "blau.png", r + "blau.png",
        r + "blau.png", r + "blau.png"
    ];

var textureCube = new THREE.TextureLoader();

textureCube.load( urls );
textureCube.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ 'cube' ];
shader.uniforms[ 'tCube' ].value = textureCube;

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide

} )

room = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1000, 1000, 1000 ), material );
sceneCube.add(room);
```

I would appreciate sooo much if someone could help me with that case :)

Comment: ok you want a room and an object in your room; so why create two cameras?

Comment: Well, it is a point. But I found this in a snippet from some ThreeJS example. To remove the cameraCube changes nothing, though.

Comment: actually you are not describing very well what the problem is?

Comment: OK, I've chaged the discription a bit. Hope it sounds clearer now :) I hope that someone just can tell me how I can create a Room, where I can place my Object

Comment: Can you not just follow [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_cube)? If you are not more specific about what isn't working nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: A "cubescene" is not actually a generally recognized term in graphics programming... could it be the effect you are after is a `Skybox`?

Comment: I will take a look at Skybox. I've noticed that normally people are picking a sphere to display a room, so maybe I will give it a try.